# Python scrapy encoding, again

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, scrapy

here is my code

```
scrapy shell "http://www.yandex.ru"
```

then

```
>>> response.encoding
'utf-8'
>>> title = response.xpath("//title/text()").extract()[0]
>>> title
u'\u042f\u043d\u0434\u0435\u043a\u0441'
```

I have no idea how i can get russian text here, try

```
>>> title.encode("utf-8")
'\xd0\xaf\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb4\xd0\xb5\xd0\xba\xd1\x81'
```

thanx

Comment: `print(title) -> Яндекс
`, you are seeing the repr output in the shell

Comment: I forgot about it, thank you very much